# Pattern matching and grep together

Tags: sed

I have a file like below

```
Event1
A
B
C
Event2
CC
CC
DD
Event1
E
N
D
Event2
```

Now I could sed between Event 1 and Event 2 and able to take all the lines between those but what I want is, if the Sed can output only if the lines between Event1 and Event2 has "B" as a content.  So my output looks like

```
Event1
A
B
C
Event2
```

Comment: Do you always have 3 rows between events?

Comment: No the rows will be uneven. But  the value of B will exist in any one of the row for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -n '/Event1/,/Event2/H;/Event2/{x;/B/p}' filename
```

Explanation:

- the sed programm has two parts: `/Event1/,/Event2/H` and `/Event2/{x;/B/p}`.
- First part: `/Event1/,/Event2/` matches all lines between `Event1` and `Event2` inclusive. the `H` puts all those lines in the so called "hold space".
- Second Part: `/Event2/{x;/B/p}` if line contains `Event2` then execute the command group `{x;/B/p}`.
- The command group also has two parts: `x` and `/B/p`.
- `x` takes everything from "hold space" and puts it in "pattern space".
- `/B/p` prints the pattern space if there is a `B` in it.

The idea in human language: take note of every line between `Event1` and `Event2`. If you see `Event2` then look at all the lines you just noted. If there is a `B` in it then print. Otherwise ignore.

---

Note the above sed program has a "bug".

If the input looks like this:

```
Event1x
A
B
C
Event2x
CC
CC
DD
Event1y
E
N
D
Event2y
CC
CC
DD
Event1z
X
B
X
Event2z
```

The output will look like this:

```
$ sed -n '/Event1/,/Event2/H;/Event2/{x;/B/p}' foo

Event1x
A
B
C
Event2x
Event2y
Event1z
X
B
X
Event2z
```

Note the `Event2y` and also the first empty line. This is because of sed peculiarities.

This modification of the sed progam replaces the `Event2y` with an empty line. which is basically the same reason for the first empty line.

```
sed -n '/Event1/,/Event2/H;/Event2/{s/.*//;x;/B/p}' filename
```

Example output

```
$ sed -n '/Event1/,/Event2/H;/Event2/{s/.*//;x;/B/p}' filename

Event1x
A
B
C
Event2x

Event1z
X
B
X
Event2z
```

The empty line can be fixed with even more sed-fu but I will need more reputation points to wrap my head around that.

---

Learn more sed!!1

- http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html
- http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/

Comment: Thank you .. Now instead of value "B" , I have a value "B  D" . When there is a space in the line I need to grep , the above one doesn't seem to work ..  I tried as below

sed -n '/Event1/,/Event2/H;/Event2/{s/.*//;x;/"B D"/p}' filename

Comment: don't put quotes around `B D`. like this `{s/.*//;x;/B D/p}`